# How to use a function that declared in first class, use it in second class?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, console

```
    class Kontak : IElektroBeyin
    {
          int x = Console.Read();
          switch(x){
          case 1: 
              //Here I want to use GetSpeed function.
            break;
          }
    }
    class Pedal : Kontak
    {
        public void GetSpeed()
        {
          Speed += 10;
        }
    }
```

Hi, I want to use a function that declared in second class. I want to use it in first class. Is that possible ? Can I use GetSpeed function in class named Kontak ? Because I don't want to write a lot of codes in main.

I tried to create an example of Pedal in Kontak class.--- Pedal p = new Pedal();--- In case1 : --- p.GetSpeed();--- Finally I controlled my Pedal's and Kontak's Speed value.  But they were both equal to zero.

Comment: No, you can't, you have to declare it in the base class (Kontak) if you want to use it in both.

Comment: (1) Your code is *very* malformed, you have code in a class outside of a method.  (2) Unless `Kontak` defines a `GetSpeed()` method, there isn't one to use in that part of the code.  You need an instance of a class which has that method.  (3) Be aware that your code seems to be needlessly confusing.  When methods called "GetX" don't actually *get* anything but *do* modify something, expect bugs.

Comment: Thank you very much. David this is not my code actually. I write this simple short code for you to understand what I asked.

Comment: By the way, what if Kontak inherits from Pedal ? Can I use GetSpeed method that way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare it like this:

```
class Kontak
{
public virtual void GetSpeed(){}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    // if overridden, it will call that method
    // otherwise it will call this class's method
    GetSpeed(); 
}
}
```

Then override it:

```
class Pedal : Kontak
{
    public override void GetSpeed()
    {
      Speed += 10;
    }
}
```